# Prepared statement not sending

Tags: php

I am having an issue with a framework I have used quite often for different sites. I copy and pasted the framework from a working website I have and changed nothing other than my database information, but for some reason I am getting multiple errors associated with my database file. I am including partial files to show the relevant code from my database file and my init file.

Does anyone see anything I am doing wrong?

I am getting errors for the following lines:

Line 13) 
Notice: Array to string conversion and Warning: PDO::__construct() expects parameter 2 to be string `$this->_pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=' . Config::get('mysql/host') . ';dbname=' . Config::get('mysql/db'), Config::get('mysql/username'), Config::get('mysql/password'));`

My debug calls out this:

`DEBUG DB::query called
SQL: SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?`

`PARAMS: test`

Then on line 33,

It gives this error:

`Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in`

For this line: `if($this->_query = $this->_pdo->prepare($sql)) {`

Database class

```
class DB {
    private static $_instance = null;
    private $_pdo,
            $_query, 
            $_error = false,
            $_results,
            $_count = 0,
            $_errmsg = "";

    private function __construct(){
        try {
            $this->_pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=' . Config::get('mysql/host') . ';dbname=' . Config::get('mysql/db'), Config::get('mysql/username'), Config::get('mysql/password'));
            /*$host = config::get('mysql/host');
            $database = config::get('mysql/db');
            $username = config::get('mysql/user');
            $pasword = config::get('mysql/password');

            $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=$host;dbname=$database', $username, $pasword);*/
            } catch(PDOException $e) {
        die($e->getMEssage());
        }   
    }
    public static function getInstance() {
        if(!isset(self::$_instance)) {
            self::$_instance = new DB();
        }
        return self::$_instance;
    }
    public function query($sql, $params = array()){
echo "DEBUG DB::query called<br>SQL: $sql<br><br>PARAMS: " . implode("<br>", $params) . "<hr>\n";       
        $this->_error = false;
        if($this->_query = $this->_pdo->prepare($sql)) {
echo "DEBUG: prepared statement created ok<hr>\n";          
            $x = 1;
            if(count($params)){
                foreach($params as $param){
                    $this->_query->bindValue($x, $param);
                    $x++;
                }
            }
            if($this->_query->execute()){
                $this->_results = $this->_query->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
                $this->_count = $this->_query->rowCount();
echo "DEBUG: query succeeded, rowcount was: " . $this->_count . "<hr>\n";               
            } else {
    "DEBUG: query failed to execute, reason:<br>" . implode( "<br>", $this->_query->errorInfo() ) . "<hr>\n";   
                $this->_error = true;
            }
        } else {
echo "DEBUG: Failed to create prepared statement<hr>\n";
        }   
        return $this;
    }
```

Init class

```
$GLOBALS['config'] = array(
    'mysqli' => array(
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'username' => 'actual',
        'password' => 'actual',
        'db' => 'actual'
    ),
    'remember' => array(
        'cookie_name' => 'hash',
        'cookie_expiry' => 604800
    ),
    'session' => array(
        'session_name' => 'user',
        'token_name' => 'token'
        )
    );

    spl_autoload_register(function($class) {
        require_once 'classes/' . $class . '.php';
    });

    require_once 'functions/sanitize.php';
```

Comment: How do you call all these methods?

Comment: Let me suggest ou to read this article of mine, [Your first database wrapper's childhood diseases](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/common_mistakes). Your class would definitely denefit from it, in many ways

Comment: `Config::get('mysql/username')` is not a string as you think. It is an array. And beside, you do not have mysql in config but mysql**i**

Comment: @Common Sense I have the `ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);` within my file. I call this through my register file. It is called out through the user file, but it isn't even making it to it yet.

Comment: This latter comment is quite irrelevant to what I posted. The problems of your class are try and catch, stateful variables, binding in a loop, returning fetchAll, wrong error handling.

Comment: If I change `mysqli` to `mysql` in my init file, I get the following error... `SQLSTATE[42000] [1044] Access denied for user 'actual'@'localhost' to database 'actual'`.

Comment: So you have to provide the actual credentials. Don't you think that credentials would be the same for all hosts, do you?

Comment: @Becky so now it is working fine. And another problem you have, that you need to fix access for your user#

Comment: I have the actual db info in my file. I just put `actual` in for this posting.