# Database call not working within sub-folder

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, frameworks, require

I am running into an issue while calling for my framework classes within a sub-folder. I had one init file that included the db calling and the routing to my different class folders. I then added a new init file to allow me to use my framework within sub-folders, such as this one circled:

[image]

Everything seems to be routing fine, except now my database class is not working right. I am getting the following errors:

Notice: Array to string conversion

Warning: PDO::__construct() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in

For this code:

```
$this->_pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=' . Config::get('mysql/host') . ';dbname=' . Config::get('mysql/db'), Config::get('mysql/username'), Config::get('mysql/password'));
```

The thing is, it works for my normal files within the root: ie: index, register, etc. It just doesn't work with the new init file calling. This is how my two init files route:

Original

```
require_once 'core/init.php';
```

Init file

```
spl_autoload_register(function($class) {
        require_once 'classes/' . $class . '.php';
    });

    require_once 'functions/sanitize.php';
```

New calling and init file:

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/../core/init_account.php';
```

New Init file

```
spl_autoload_register(function($class) {
        require_once '../classes/' . $class . '.php';
    });

    require_once '../functions/sanitize.php';
```

Does anyone see why the following code works with my original init file, but not my new one?

```
$this->_pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=' . Config::get('mysql/host') . ';dbname=' . Config::get('mysql/db'), Config::get('mysql/username'), Config::get('mysql/password'));
```

Rest of init file:

```
$GLOBALS['config'] = array(
    'mysqli' => array(
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'username' => 'actual',
        'password' => 'actual',
        'db' => 'actual'
    ),
    'remember' => array(
        'cookie_name' => 'hash',
        'cookie_expiry' => 604800
    ),
    'session' => array(
        'session_name' => 'user',
        'token_name' => 'token'
        )
    );
```

Edit: Config Class:

```
class Config {
    public static function get ($path = null) {
        if($path) {
            $config = $GLOBALS['config'];
            $path = explode('/', $path);

            foreach($path as $bit) {
                if(isset($config[$bit])){
                    $config = $config[$bit];
                }
            }
            return $config;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: What about dumping the actual content of that second parameter?

Comment: Like this? `var_dump('Config::get('mysql/db')');` I am getting an error for that. ..... Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'mysql' (T_STRING)

Comment: OMG. Like this var_dump(Config::get('mysql/db')); So you are writing a framework?

Comment: @YourCommonSense Thanks...sorry pretty new to all of this. It appears to be dumping all of the correct info... `array(3) { ["mysqli"]=> array(4) { ["host"]=> string(9) "localhost" ["username"]=> string(12) "actual" ["password"]=> string(8) "actual" ["db"]=> string(12) "actual" } ["remember"]=> array(2) { ["cookie_name"]=> string(4) "hash" ["cookie_expiry"]=> int(604800) } ["session"]=> array(2) { ["session_name"]=> string(4) "user" ["token_name"]=> string(5) "token" } }`

Comment: Correct info? All this stuff is going to be the username for mysql connection?

Comment: No, the username is only the username described in the dumped info. However, it should have only dumped the database info right? I added for of my init file to my question. I do not get how it works in the root of my site, but not in this sub-folder.

Comment: We have no idea either. Why your Config::get() method is dumping whole config instead of returning just single value.

Comment: Is there anything else I can do to figure it out?

Comment: well you can show us (or examine yourself) what is in Config::get() function. BTW: you want to get MYSQL but in config you have MYSQLI

Comment: Yes. The best way would be to get rid of this erroneous framework as is turns out [this is not the first time it goes wild](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39960559/prepared-statement-not-sending)

Comment: It turns out the mysqli I had in my init file was causing the errors. For some reason I put `mysqli` in the new init file, when it wasn't in the original. That fixed this. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @YourCommonSense I figured out my previous question. I set up the db wrong is terms of the password row. It set it up `varchar 50` in stead of 64. That was causing the issue.